# I cannot get list values to be preserved in helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

For some reason I cannot get list values to be preserved in helm template:

**job.yaml**:

```
args: {{  .Values.args  }}
```

**values.yaml**:

```
args: ["-c","echo 'test'; sleep 5"]
```

**helm template --debug**:

```
args: [-c echo 'test'; sleep 5]
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `{{  .Values.args  }}`, you get the value from the values file as go data structure, so that you may use it in different ways.
In your case, this is a slice. If you print a slice in go, it will look like this `[a b c]`, no commas or quotes, for example. That's what you see here.

The usual technique is using `toJson` or `toYaml`.

```yaml
args: {{- .Values.args | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
args: {{ .Values.args | toJson }}
```

Note, the value for `nindent` depends on where in your template you use this. 2 is probably not correct, it should be at least 2 more indented than args is in your template.

Answer (score 0):

In job.yaml modify it like this to make it work-

`args: [{{  .Values.args  }}]`

And for values.yaml:

`args: "-c","echo 'test'; sleep 5"`